# Как в данной программе каждый раз высчитывается новое значение result?

Tags: java

Только учусь java и разбираю цикл while.
Наткнулся на непонятный мне момент в задаче.
Как я понял переменная result в первый круг цикла не рассчитывается и в консоль выводится ее изначальное 
значение - 1. На втором круге цикла переменная result рассчитывается как 1*2=2 и выводится 
в консоль на 2-ой строке.
Но как она меняется дальше??? Ей инициализировано значение 1, которое как я понял циклом никак не меняется, соответственно на последующих кругах цикла переменная result всегда рассчитывается как 
1*2=2, но на консоль в последующих строках выходят значения переменной result равные 4, 8 и 16.
Как это происходит? Что я упускаю и не так понимаю? Где-то переменная result все же циклится как бы?

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int e;
    int result;

    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        result = 1;
        e = i;
        while(e > 0) {
            result *=2;                     
            e--;
        }
        System.out.println(" - 2 в степени " + i + " равно " + result);
    }
}
```

}

- 2 в степени 0 равно 1        // На консоль вот так выводится
- 2 в степени 1 равно 2
- 2 в степени 2 равно 4
- 2 в степени 3 равно 8
- 2 в степени 4 равно 16

Comment: result *=2; эта запись эквивалентна записи result = result * 2; имено здесь меняется ваша переменная result

Comment: извиняюсь за спам
Тоже не понимаю решения этой задачи: в начале каждой итерации result приравнивается к 1. Почему программа запоминает расчет от прошлой итерации... Я пробовала строку result=1 выносить до цикла for, в итоге программа половину степеней выводит корректно, а половину - какой-то кашей. И строка e-- всё равно не дает покоя: говорят она завершает цикл while. Допустим итерация i=2, e до цикла while =2, на входе в while проверяем условие 2>0 - верно, входим в while. На выходе из while e=2-1=1, как это значение завершает цикл?

Comment: @user440327 result находится во внешней для for области видимости. То есть той (в данном случае это метод main), которая удалится (вместе со время данными) уже после завершения for. Выход из while будет только есть e либо меньше, либо равно 0, или если e строго меньше 1

Comment: @user440327 если `e==2` перед входом в цикл while, то цикл выполнится два раза. первый проход `e==2` на входе в цикл, второй проход - `e==1`. После второго прохода `е==0` => условие while не выполняется => выходим из цикла. Два прохода, и на каждом умножаем начальное значение `result==1` на 2, те получаем `1*2*2` т.е. 2 в степени 2, что и требовалось.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(e > 0) {
            result *=2;                     
            e--;
        }
```

В этом цикле каждую итерацию происходит умножение на 2 переменной `result` и уменьшение переменной `e` на 1. То есть, `result` умножается на 2 количество раз, равное `e`.